# Персонаж не прыгает в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

делал игру и все делал как на ютубе, но его челик прыгает когда стоит на блоке, а у меня не прыгает даже когда стоит. Коллайдеры вроде все настроены правильно, либо чел не понимает что он стоит на блоке либо что-то другое. На [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2jSVcpdWjs&ab_channel=Martino) видно, там он прыгнул когда упирается об стенку блока. Приложу код

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 3f; // скорость движения
    [SerializeField] private int lives = 5; // скорость движения
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 15f; // сила прыжка
    private bool isGrounded = false;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckGround();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
            Run();
        if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            Jump();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Vector3 dir = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + dir, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        sprite.flipX = dir.x < 0.0f;
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    private void CheckGround()
    {
        Collider2D[] collider = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, 0.3f);
        isGrounded = collider.Length > 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: вероятнее всего неправильно размещается OverlapCircleAll в методе CheckGround. Необходимо уточнить код в этом месте. Или позиция неправильная, или сфера слишком маленькая или единицу нужно поменять на иное значение.

Comment: А так вообще необходимо дебажить этот метод. Со стороны тебе вряд ли кто подскаже в чем дело без дебага.

Comment: Вообще смысл таков: нужно основы языка изучать, а не копировать какой-то непонятный текст из видосов инфоциган на ютубе. Так ничему не научишся.

Comment: Основу языка знаю. но в юнити там свои библиотеки о которых я не знаю

Comment: Если ты не знаешь как дебажить код - то ты не знаешь основ языка.